# Problem with proof environment in Elsevier class

Tags: environments, elsarticle

I am using the follwoing code to write proofs in the elsarticle class. (This is exactly the code suggested in the documentation.)

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

\newproof{pf}{Proof}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{pf}
Some proof.
\end{pf}

\end{document}
```

However, there's no square at the end of the proof! (Additionally, I think the word proof should be in bold, which is not the case.) Is there a problem with the class? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try using `\qed`?

Comment: I guess this does work, but the documentation makes it seem like I shouldn't have to use an extra command...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newly defined `pf` environment makes no attempt whatsoever to automatically add a QED tombstone.

You might manually add `\qed` at the end, but its definition is very simplistic and would need work.

However, the documentation of `elsarticle` says

> Users can also make use of `amsthm.sty` which will override all the default definitions described above.

Do it and use the provided `proof` environment.

By the way, the class has

```
\def\@opargbeginproof#1#2#3{\trivlist\let\baselinestretch\@blstr
      \item[\hskip \labelsep{\scshape #1\ (#3).}]\rmfamily}
```

so the label is in small caps by choice (contrary to what the documentation shows).

If you want the “Proof” label in boldface when using `amsthm`, you can patch it.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\itshape}{\prooflabelfont}{}{}
\newcommand{\prooflabelfont}{\bfseries}

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}


\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Some proof.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]